# Can't save Kendo UI Scheduler event

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, scheduler

You can reproduce all next steps on standard kendo UI Scheduler example. For example on this: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/scheduler/how-to/dynamic-calc-of-height

1. Click on empty time slot.
2. Editor pop up is opening for creating new event
3. Type title etc.
4. Click "Save"

Now we see new event on the scheduler table.
But if we do next:

1. Click on event
2. Editor pop up is opening for editing event
3. Click on cancel.
4. Scheduler - delete the event!

How to save event and prevent this scheduler incomprehensible behavior?

---

But on this example all works fine.
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/scheduler/how-to/add-control-to-customeditor
Please, explain some one, what is happens? What is the reason of different behavior?

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to Stack Overflow. If you feel my reply solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.That way, people who find the question using Google can have more assurance that the answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is the missing dataSource "schema.model" configuration which is mandatory for the CRUD operations. For more information about how to set up the Scheduler you can check the following help article:

- [Scheduler: overview](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/scheduler/overview)